# Send all emails to specific email address instead for development in django

Tags: django

I would like to redirect all emails normally sent with send_mail() to me(and only me) when I work locally on the project.

I'm aware that I could use the file backend or console backend to see the emails but I need to be able to open the attached files so I can inspect them. Is there any way to do this easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's suposse you have a variable with the destination email.

```
destination_email = ...
```

In your settings add this:

```
# settings.py
DEBUG = True

...

DEBUG_DESTINATION_EMAIL = 'youremail@yourdomain.com'
```

So, where you send the email:

```
from django.conf import settings

...

if settings.DEBUG:
    destination_email = settings.DEBUG_DESTINATION_EMAIL
else:
    destination_email = ...  # get the destination email normally
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing your own custom email backend. You could subclass the smtp backend and change the recipients address before the email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Try [django-email-bandit](https://github.com/caktus/django-email-bandit)

Quoted from their readme.

---

To install django-email-bandit via pip:

```
pip install django-email-bandit
```

Add django-email-bandit to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'bandit',
    ...
)
```

For your test environment you should enable the backend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'bandit.backends.smtp.HijackSMTPBackend'
```

and set the email which will receive all of the emails:

```
BANDIT_EMAIL = 'bandit@example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just writing simple email backend to send all emails to my debug email address.

```
import smtplib

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend


class TestEmailBackend(EmailBackend):

    def _send(self, email_message):
        message = email_message.message()
        try:
            self.connection.sendmail(settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, settings.TEST_EMAIL_ADDRESS, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
        except smtplib.SMTPException:
            if not self.fail_silently:
                raise
            return False
        return True
```

You should set your email in `TEST_EMAIL_ADDRESS` variable in your `settings.py` and set `EMAIL_BACKEND` to `'path.to.your.module.TestEmailBackend'`